# Why is my flask route saving xlsx file to the root directory of the project instead of instance files?

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

I am trying to create a flask route that sends data to a function, that function creates an openpyxl excel file and returns the excel file to the route, and the route then returns the downloadable file to a React frontend. I'm not sure if this is the exact problem, but I am getting errors that the file is not found in my instance/files folder. Instead, the file is saving to my project's root directory. The same path is working for other routes, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here/why it is saving elsewhere. I'm assuming this is why I can't return the excel file to the frontend, but it could be other issues with my function/route. Please help!

This is my openpyxl function:

```
  def generate_prev_sim_csv(data):
    get_dict = data
    claims = data['claims']
    setup_dict = data['setups']
    summary_metric_headers = data['setupSummaryMetricHeaders']
   
    filename = "Simulation_Summary.xlsx"
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active

    # styles
    heading_font = Font(size=11, bold=True)
    heading = NamedStyle(name='Heading')
    wb.add_named_style(heading)
    heading.font = heading_font

    percent_value = NamedStyle(name='Percentage')
    wb.add_named_style(percent_value)
    percent_value.number_format = '0.00%'

    # Claim Header
    headers = ['Claim']
    start_claim_header_row = 1
    start_claim_header_col = 2

    for i, header in enumerate(headers):
        current_row = start_claim_header_row
        column_letter = get_column_letter(start_claim_header_col)
        cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
        sheet[cell_ref] = header
        sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

    # Setup Header
    setup_title = "Setup "
    start_setup_header_row = 1
    start_setup_header_col = 3

    for header_index, header in enumerate(setup_dict):
        current_row = start_setup_header_row
        column_letter = get_column_letter(start_setup_header_col)
        cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
        sheet[cell_ref] = setup_title + str(header_index)
        sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

        for col_index, col_data in enumerate(setup_dict):
            current_col = start_setup_header_col + 1
            column_letter = get_column_letter(current_col)
            cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
            sheet[cell_ref] = setup_title + str(col_index + 1)
            sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

    # Side by Side Claim and Claim States Table
    starting_col_index = 2
    starting_row_index = 2

    for index, claim in enumerate(claims):
        current_row = starting_row_index + index
        column_letter = get_column_letter(starting_col_index)
        cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
        sheet[cell_ref] = claim
        sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

        for i, setup in enumerate(setup_dict):
            setup_claims_on = setup[3]
            current_col = starting_col_index + i + 1
            column_letter = get_column_letter(current_col)
            cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
            if claim in setup_claims_on:
                sheet[cell_ref] = setup[2][claim]['Summary_Metrics']['Reach']
                sheet[cell_ref].style = percent_value
            elif setup[0][claim] == "Offered":
                sheet[cell_ref] = "Already Offered"
            elif setup[0][claim] == "Considered":
                sheet[cell_ref] = "Considered"
            elif setup[0][claim] == "Excluded":
                sheet[cell_ref] = "Excluded"
            else:
                sheet[cell_ref] = ""

    # Summary Metrics Header
    start_metric_header_row = 16
    start_metric_header_col = 2

    for i, header in enumerate(summary_metric_headers):
        current_row = start_metric_header_row
        column_letter = get_column_letter(start_metric_header_col)
        cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
        sheet[cell_ref] = "Summary Metrics"
        sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

    # Summary Metrics Table

    start_col_index = 2
    start_row_index = 17

    for i, header in enumerate(summary_metric_headers):
        current_row = start_row_index + i
        column_letter = get_column_letter(start_col_index)
        cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
        sheet[cell_ref] = header
        sheet[cell_ref].style = heading

        for id, setup in enumerate(setup_dict):
            current_col = starting_col_index + id + 1
            column_letter = get_column_letter(current_col)
            cell_ref = f"{column_letter}{current_row}"
            if header == "Subgroup":
                sheet[cell_ref] = setup[5]
            elif header == "Number of Respondents":
                sheet[cell_ref] = setup[4]
            elif header == "Average Liked":
                sheet[cell_ref] = round(setup[1]["Average_Number_of_Items_Liked"], 2)
            elif header == "Average Reach":
                sheet[cell_ref] = setup[1]["Reach"]
                sheet[cell_ref].style = percent_value
            elif header == "Average Favorite":
                sheet[cell_ref] = setup[1]["Favorite_Percentage"]
                sheet[cell_ref].style = percent_value
            else:
                sheet[cell_ref] = ""

    wb.save(filename=filename)

    return filename
```

This is my route. I'm not sure what to do with the return from the function?:

```
@bp.route("/api/export_prev_sim_to_csv", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def export_simulations_to_csv():
    data = request.get_json() or {}
    print(data)
    if not os.path.exists(current_app.instance_path):
        os.mkdir(current_app.instance_path)
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(current_app.instance_path, "files")):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(current_app.instance_path, "files"))
    cs_fn = os.path.join(
        current_app.instance_path, "files", "Simulation_Summary.xlsx"
    )
    openpyxl_file = generate_prev_sim_csv(data)
    return send_file(
        cs_fn,
        mimetype=(
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        ),
        as_attachment=True,
        cache_timeout=0,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the file in root directory in `generate_prev_sim_csv` function

```py
filename = "Simulation_Summary.xlsx"
[...]
wb.save(filename=filename)
```

Wb.save creates a file if it doesn't exist so you don't need to create file in your route

Just change the filename to this in your openpyxl function

```py
filename = 'instance/files/Simulation_Summary.xlsx'
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I changed it, but I am still getting the error No such file or directory. If I replace the filename in the openpyxl function, do I need to remove the os.path lines from the route & only run the generate_prev_sim_csv function?

Comment: Actually I got it! Thank you for your help :)